# Arrival Distributions

Tags: anylogic

Working on my model, set up a custom distribution for the agents to arrive in a bimodal distribution to simulate peaks during the day. To be clear, the agent has a parameter called 'arrivals', and we have a custom distribution connected to the agent, where the distribution for 'arrivals' is set to the custom distribution. And finally, the source has the arrival rate set to the aforementioned custom distribution.
However, upon running the model, the arrivals seem to be coming a lot faster than I intend on modelling. 
The distributions are set 'per hour'.

Here are screenshots of the source settings and the custom distribution
[Source_Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSuYr.png)
[Distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whNiE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your source block is not re-drawing a different rate everytime it creates an agent, as you likely expect. Instead, it is defining a fixed rate once at the model start (by chance, it is on the faster end of the distr) and keeps that. Read how the Rate setting works and make sure this is what you want. You probably want the "Interarrival time" setting instead as here, a new value is drawn everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Well, did you make sure the Source object also expects the arrivals to be "per hour"?

Sounds like you are still in the default "per second" mode...
[image]

Comment: Hello! Yes, unfortunately, I do have the sources set at 'per hour'

Comment: well, you need to be more explicit then in your description. Best upload some screenshots as well of how you set this up. Hard to help otherwise :-) How did you connect distributions to agent params, where do agents live...

Comment: Hello, I added some screenshots to the original question, I hope it's easier to see the problem now.

Comment: And what does the cust-distr look like?

Comment: doesn't really matter, check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55116386/2164728 (and if this helped, please flag it as "solved" to help others find it in the future)